# Windows Embedded HTTP Server with Bonjour(Zeroconf) Support

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bonjour, httpserver

I need to find or create an HTTP server that will run on a Windows machine and announce its presence via Bonjour(Zeroconf). I've searched all over the web and can't seem to find anything that fits the bill or even any information about how I would go about adding the Bonjour functionality to a server that I create.

I found that apache has mod_zeroconf, but it only runs under Linux and found that Apple provides a Bonjour installer for Windows, but it doesn't appear to add the announce functionality. I feel like I may be searching in the wrong places.

For my current project I'm ok with using something off-the-shelf, building with C#/.Net, or even rolling a rails/rack based server and setting up the announcement as a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll need to integrate [Mono.Zeroconf](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf).